# Writing a function to perform Collatz Conjecture

Tags: python, function, while-loop, collatz

I am asked to complete the rest of this code:

```
def collatz_step(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2
```

and write a while loop that will set n to the next value given by collatz_step until it reaches 1, printing the value of n at each step.

which I completed as follows, which should give me 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

```
def collatz_step(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2
    else:
        return 3*n + 1

while n != 1:
    n = collatz_step(n)
    print(n)

collatz_step(3)
```

but I get an error saying that 'n' is not defined? this part specifically,

```
while n != 1:
```

how do I solve this to get the correct results?

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear.

Comment: Did you mean for that `while` loop to be a part of the `collatz_step` function somehow?  It's not really clear what value you're *expecting* `n` to have on that line or why.

Comment: `n` is only defined within the **scope** of the `collatz_step` function. The `while` loop is outside that function, where indeed `n` is not defined.

Comment: can I not do that? because what I want to do is while n is not 1, run the while loop on the `collatz_step(n)` and print out the results until n reaches 1

Comment: You never told python that you wanted `n = 3` prior to entering the while loop.

Comment: I tried `n = collatz_step(n)` just above the `while`, and it didn't work, so do I have to put the `while` inside the `def` ?

Comment: `collatz_step` is designed to do a single step. You did it correctly and shouldn't modify it. The solution is to just have `n = 3` prior to the while loop if you want `n = 3`. Don't over-complicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things wrong:

1. You never define `n` before trying to use it.
2. At the end you call the function again but do nothing with the result.

It sounds like you just want to define `n` and then call the function in your loop, not again at the end.  So something like:

```
# no changes to the function definition

n = 3
while n != 1:
    n = collatz_step(n)
    print(n)
```

Just think about it semantically... You want to start with a value of `3` and then repeat the operation of updating that value until it equals `1`.  So first you define a variable with the value you want, then you write a loop in which you update that value until the loop condition is met.